# Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! (Pgs4a -Android.py build release)

Tags: python, android, apk

I am creating an apk from pygame using pgs4a.  I am able to configure my game using `android.py configure mygame`

The next step is to build it using 
`android.py build mygame release`

But it shows error `build.xml not found and hence build failed`. 
How to fix it?

Using windows10